# laravel relationship not loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I've got a `Product` and a `Category` models:

```
class Product extends BaseModel
{
    use Uuid;

    protected $fillable = [
        'barcode',
        'name',
        'sku',
        'description',
        'type',
        'category_id',
        'wholesale_price',
        'retail_price',
        'base_picture',
        'current_stock_level',
        'active',
    ];

    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

```
class Category extends BaseModel
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'parent',
        'description',
        'image',
    ];

    public function product(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

In my controller, I'm retrieveing all products and wanted to return the category object the product belongs to in the response, so I'm doing:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(): AnonymousResourceCollection
    {
       $products = Product::all();
        return ProductsResource::collection($products->loadMissing('category'));
    }
```

and my resource looks like:

```
class ProductsResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request) : array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'type' => 'products',
            'attributes' => [
                'barcode' => $this->barcode,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'slug' => $this->slug,
                'sku' => $this->sku,
                'description' => $this->description,
                'type' => $this->type,
                // todo return  category object?
                'category' => new CategoriesResource($this->whenLoaded('category_id')),
                'wholesale_price' => $this->wholesale_price,
                'retail_price' => $this->retail_price,
                'base_picture' => $this->base_picture,
                'current_stock_level' => $this->current_stock_level,
                'active' => $this->active,
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

but the response I'm getting is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "a2102c4c-c14a-4d16-af28-e218bcc4fe39",
            "type": "products",
            "attributes": {
                "barcode": "1010101010101",
                "name": "phione",
                "slug": "phione",
                "sku": "w2e2r2",
                "description": null,
                "type": "services",
                "wholesale_price": 54,
                "retail_price": 34,
                "base_picture": null,
                "current_stock_level": 0,
                "active": 1
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

I tried loading the relationship differently:

```
public function index(): AnonymousResourceCollection
{
     $products = Product::with('category')->get();
     return ProductsResource::collection($products);
}
```

but the result is the same.

It seems that the relationship is well established because if I run:

```
$product = Product::first();
dd($product->category);
```

I can see the category the product belongs to:

```
#attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Paper"
    "slug" => "paper"
    "parent" => 1
    "description" => null
    "image" => null
    "created_at" => "2022-09-20 02:03:05"
    "updated_at" => "2022-09-20 02:03:05"
  ]
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller load `category` relation with eager loading

```
$products = Product::with('category');
return ProductsResource::collection($products);
```

and in the **ProductsResource** file load, the relation `category`, not `category_id`

```
'category' => CategoriesResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('category')),
```

Comment: that was the issue, thanks!

Comment: use this `$products = Product::with('category');`. This will reduce database queries sent to Database and make the application process faster.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a collection here. Simply do

```
$products = Product::with('category')->get();
return response()->json($products);
```

Comment: the problem is not whether i need the collection or not, the problem is that the relationship is not loading. I had tried before what you're suggesting but still the relationship is not loaded

Comment: What is the output of print_r($products->toArray()) ? Can you please share.